# Why do I get a Unicode error when piping output containing Unicode from Python 2 to grep?

Tags: grep, python

I have a python script to output unicode codepoints and character names for a collection of useful characters to the terminal (xfce4-terminal).  It's getting a bit big so I tried piping the output through grep, and was surprised to get a *python* error.  A grep error wouldn't have surprised me; I would have assumed that grep wasn't set up for unicode input.

A simple one-line demo of the error:

```
python -c 'print "diameter "+ unichr(0x2300)'|grep 'd'
```

returns

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2300' in position 9: 
ordinal not in range(128)`
```

My default python is Python 2 (Xubuntu 18.04 and lots of legacy python 2 code).  Adding

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

to the script makes no difference (It shouldn't as the script is all in ASCII).

If I update my script to Python 3 and run it like  `python3 -c 'print ("diameter "+ unichr(0x2300))'|grep 'd'` it works. This means a shebang explicitly calling python3, and making the script executable, also works. Despite being able to work round it, I'm curious as to what's going on:

How and why does python 2 know it's outputting to a pipeline to grep, and not to the terminal directly, and go on to run differently?

Comment: [python2 is depreciated as of Jan 2020](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/).  It would be better to move away from it completely.  Some tools and languages detect what they're writing to and will behave differently when piped vs writing to a terminal. I wonder if writing to a terminal triggers python2 to change which characterset it's trying to write

Comment: This stack overflow answer might help you fix it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9942822/453851

Comment: @PhilipCouling I know, but try finding time/effort/someone to convert a research group's legacy code. It's generally low-risk data collection/processing stuff and hard to follow. I'm trying to write new stuff for python3 with a suitable shebang because changing the default would break too much

Comment: Either the answer (append `.encode('utf-8')` to the string variable name when printing) or a  comment (`export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8` before running the script) fixed it. If that other Q was on the same site I'd flag as a dupe (but I probably would have found it before asking).  I'm not sure if cross-site duplicates are supported

Comment: I think there's a more indepth discussion of your issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python/7892892#7892892

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not uncommon for programs to detect whether or not they their stdout is attached to a terminal or something else.  The function `isatty()` [is part of posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/isatty.html) and is used quite a bit.

A really common example is that you get significantly different output between the two following commands:

```
ls
ls | cat
```

---

In python2's case it looks like it changes with the default encoding that python uses:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python/7892892#7892892

This is clearly a conscious design decision but it's unclear what the advantage of it is.

The recommendation in the referenced answer is to set: `PYTHONIOENCODING`

---

[Python2 is depreciated](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/).  You should try to switch to python 3 anyway.

This doesn't answer the question of why they are different, but some simple searches on google show up why it fails.  [This Stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9942822/453851) points to the very first example on this documentation:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unichr

The short version is you are not converting your unicode string to bytes before adding it to an askii string.